# I have a figure with 2 axes, how do I make them have the same scale in y axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, graph

This is the code. The two axes have two different scales. (ax1 has both negative and positive values and ax2 has only negative values). The graph should be such a way that ax1 would have one line(the positive points) on top of the x-axis and the other line (with negative x-ticks) under the x-axis. Same for ax2.

you can see the resultant graph here:
[image: The resultant graph is shown here]

```
x_ax = list(np.arange(10))
y_ax = list(np.arange(-10,0))
x_ax1 = list(np.arange(10))
y_ax1 = list(np.arange(0,10))
x_ax_p = list(np.arange(10))
y_ax_p = list(np.arange(-30,-20))
x_ax1_p = list(np.arange(10))
y_ax1_p = list(np.arange(-40,-30))



fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.9,0.1,0.8,0.8])
ax1.spines['left'].set_color('none')
# ax1.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax1.spines['top'].set_color('none')
# ax1.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
# ax2.spines['left'].set_position(('axes', 0))
ax2.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax2.spines['top'].set_color('none')
# ax2.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
#ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])
#ax2.set_xticks([])
ax2.set_yticks([])
x_offset= 0.2 # for displaying the values
y_offset= 2 
##################enter code here#########################
ax1.plot(range(len(x_ax)),y_ax,marker='o', label = 'Test_store')
ax1.plot(range(len(x_ax1)),y_ax1,marker='o', label = 'Control_store')

##############################################
ax2.plot(range(len(x_ax_p)),y_ax_p,marker='o', label = 'Test_store')
ax2.plot(range(len(x_ax1_p)),y_ax1_p,marker='o', label = 'Control_store')

for i,j in zip(range(len(x_ax)),y_ax):
    ax1.annotate(round(j,2),xy=(i,j),xytext = (i,j))
for i,j in zip(range(len(x_ax1)),y_ax1):
    ax1.annotate(str(round(j,2)),xy=(i,j),xytext = (i,j))
for i,j in zip(range(len(x_ax_p)),y_ax_p):
    ax2.annotate(str(round(j,2)),xy=(i,j),xytext = (i,j))
for i,j in zip(range(len(x_ax1_p)),y_ax1_p):
    ax2.annotate(str(round(j,2)),xy=(i,j),xytext = (i,j))

ax1.text(8.5, -15, 'Week', ha='right')
ax1.set_ylabel("Sales")
ax1.set_title("Period : "+ per + " "+ "\n" +"Week vs Sales")
ax2.set_title("Period : "+"Pilot Phase"+ "\n"+"Week vs Sales")
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(x_ax)))
ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(len(x_ax)))
ax2.legend()
plt.show()
fig.clear()
```

Comment: What specifically are you having difficulty with?

Comment: The 2 axes have different scaling. I want them to have uniform scaling.

Comment: Basically what I need is to see the comparison of the two graphs, that's why I have made the axes like the one you see in the image.

Answer (score 1):

To specify the same y-axis limits for both figures, you can use `set_ylim`:

```
ymin, ymax = 0, 100  # Change these to whatever values you require
ax1.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
ax2.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
```

You could also use the minimum and maximum of the default y-limits generated by Matplotlib to set the limits dynamically, i.e. without having to specify them manually:

```
ymin = min([ax1.get_ylim()[0], ax2.get_ylim()[0]])
ymax = max([ax1.get_ylim()[1], ax2.get_ylim()[1]])
ax1.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
ax2.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
```

To set the vertical location of the x-axis ticks at zero, you can use the following:

```
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
```

If you want to use a value other than zero, the above is shorthand for:

```
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_position(("data", 0))
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_position(("data", 0))
```

Comment: Thanks! but how do we make the negative points appear under the x-axis?

Comment: Just set the `ymin` value to a negative value at or below the minimum plotted points

Comment: I tried that but the negative values are still coming over the x-axis.

Comment: You are welcome - I've also updated to show how to set any arbitrary value (not just zero)

Comment: All of this time I had the answer in my code. I have some reading to do. * facepalm *